# Dropbox java api get file details

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I am java developer.I need to get file information from dropbox using java api.
I tried with metadata class.Here i am getting only id,name,path,size of the file.
But i need to get other information like owner name,mimetype,Createddate

```
ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolderBuilder("")
                .withIncludeDeleted(false)
                .withRecursive(true)
                .withIncludeMediaInfo(true)
                .start();
 while (true) {
            List<Metadata> entries = result.getEntries();
            int idx = 0;

            for (Metadata metadata : entries) {
  if (metadata instanceof FolderMetadata) {
                    System.out.println("" + ++idx + ": FOLDER [" + metadata.getPathDisplay() + "], [" + metadata.getName() + "]");

                } else if (metadata instanceof FileMetadata) {
                    System.out.println("" + ++idx + ": File [" + metadata.getPathDisplay() + "], [" + metadata.getName() + "]");

                String filePath = metadata.getPathLower().replace(metadata.getName().toLowerCase(), "");
                System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
                System.out.println("FILE PATH"+filePath);
  System.out.println("Dropbox"+((FileMetadata) metadata).getRev());
                        System.out.println("Dropbox"+((FileMetadata) metadata).getClientModified());


                        System.out.println("Dropbox"+((FileMetadata) metadata).getMediaInfo());
                        System.out.println("Dropbox"+((FileMetadata) metadata).getMediaInfo().getMetadataValue());
                        System.out.println("Dropbox"+((FileMetadata) metadata).getSharingInfo());
```

..

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

The `FileMetadata` object that you get back is documented here:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html

It doesn't offer the additional information you're looking for, and there isn't another way to get it via the API, but we'll consider this a feature request.

You can keep your own file extension to mime type mapping if you'd like though. For example, you can find our groupings for some file types permission here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/reference/devguide